# Firebase Firestore: Query with logical OR and pagination

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I know that there's no real logical "OR" in Firestore queries. That's why I usually do two separate queries and merge the results on the client side.

However I need to add pagination now. For pagination, merging the results from Firestore on the client side will not work obviously.

**EDIT:** Some more information on my database scheme:

```
// Collection: 'items'
doc-id-1
   provider_id: 'ABCDE'
   company_id: 'FGHIJ'

doc-id-2
   provider_id: 'KLMNO'
   company_id: 'ABCDE'

doc-id-3
   provider_id: 'ABCDE'
   company_id: 'ABCDE'

doc-id-4
   provider_id: 'KLMNO'
   company_id: 'KLMNO'
```

Here's my example:

```
// Get items by provider
db_query = this.db.collection('items').ref
    .where('provider_id', '==', 'ABCDE');

// OR

// Get items by company
db_query = this.db.collection('items').ref
    .where('company_id', '==', 'ABCDE');

/* 
   Combining the queries above with a logical OR should return
   the following documents (from my database scheme further up):
     - doc-id-1
     - doc-id-2
     - doc-id-3
*/
```

I need to combine these queries (get `items`, where `provider_id` **OR** `company_id` has a given value).

My pagination works as the following (default approach in Firestore):

```
// Query type (init, next page, prev page, fallback)
if (query_type == 'init') {
  db_query = db_query.limit(limit);

} else if (query_type == 'next') {
  db_query = db_query.startAfter(last_in_response).limit(limit);

} else if (query_type == 'prev') {
  db_query = db_query.endBefore(first_in_response).limitToLast(limit);

} else {
  db_query = db_query.limit(limit);
}
```

Is there any way to solve this? If I still combine the results on the client side, my pagination cursors won't be correct. Therefore I need to somehow cascade the query but I can't find the right approach for that.

Thank you in advance for any hints!

Comment: Do you only want to merge those two queries, i.e. searching for all docs in the **same** `items` collection where `provider_id` or `company_id` equals the same value (`ABCDE` in your example)?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I added some sample data of my database scheme and the collection 'items'. Furthermore I added an example which documents the queries with some sort of logical "OR" should return. Both fields (provider_id and company_id) can be equal but can be different also.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I had understood it the way you detailed it, so the proposed solution in my answer is still valid! :-) I'll add some few more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to combine these queries (get `items`, where `provider_id` OR
> `company_id` has a given value).

In your specific case (i.e. searching for all docs in the **same** `items` collection where `provider_id` or `company_id` equals the same value) you could denormalize your data and, for example, have an extra field `provider_company_ids` of type array, with two elements. The first element will hold the value of `provider_id` and the second element will hold the value of `company_id`.

Then you can use the [`array-contains`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) operator as follows:

```
db_query = this.db.collection('items').ref
.where("provider_company_ids", "array-contains", "ABCDE");
```

and you'll be able to correctly paginate since it's now a **single** query.

---

**Update following your comment added under your question:**

After implementing the above solution, your docs will look as follows:

```
// Collection: 'items'
doc-id-1
   provider_id: 'ABCDE'
   company_id: 'FGHIJ'
   provider_company_ids: ['ABCDE', 'FGHIJ']  // New field of type array

doc-id-2
   provider_id: 'KLMNO'
   company_id: 'ABCDE'
   provider_company_ids: ['KLMNO', 'ABCDE']

doc-id-3
   provider_id: 'ABCDE'
   company_id: 'ABCDE'
   provider_company_ids: ['ABCDE', 'ABCDE']

doc-id-4
   provider_id: 'KLMNO'
   company_id: 'KLMNO'
   provider_company_ids: ['KLMNO', 'KLMNO']
```

---

PS: I'm not sure what is the `ref` property in your code (`db_query = this.db.collection('items').ref.where('provider_id', '==', 'ABCDE');`). I re-used it as such in my anwser, making the assumption that `this.db.collection('items').ref` returns a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Query).

Comment: Elegant solution, works perfectly. Thank you!